# Using a TabControl with a grouped CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf, xaml

My VM exposes a property called 'Results', which is an ObservableCollection of 'Result' objects:

```
public class Result
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

There are only a handful of unique categories, but there can be many individual results in each category.

In my XAML I've wrapped this property in a CollectionViewSource, and applied grouping on the 'CategoryName':

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="resultsCollection"
                          Source="{Binding Results}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="CategoryName" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

What I would like to do (assuming it is possible), is create a `TabControl` with a tab per category, and the tab's header text being set to the CategoryName. Within each TabItem I would like an ItemsControl simply populated with the Description of each item (belonging to that category).

At the moment I'm even struggling to get the tab items up and running. The closest I've got is this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource resultsCollection}}">
    <TabControl.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
             <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                 </DataTemplate>
             </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </TabControl.GroupStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Assuming that I'm even on the right track, all this produces is a horizontal list TextBlocks where the tabs should be, but they aren't working, clickable tabs.

And I don't know where to start to get an ItemsControl in each TabItem!

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not quite on the right track. `TabControl` functionality is based on the item containers being `TabItem` controls. But in case of using `GroupStyle`, each item representing a group is contained in a `GroupItem` control, which breaks the `TabControl` functionality.

Key information here is that `{Binding Source={StaticResource resultsCollection}}` actually evaluates to an [`ICollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) object (usually a `ListCollectionView`). So the solution here is to bind to the [`ICollectionView.Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which contains the first-level group items (which are [`CollectionViewGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup(v=vs.110).aspx) objects). Then you can list grouped items by specifying `TabControl.ContentTemplate` and binding to the [`CollectionViewGroup.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection.

This is a bare minimum to accomplish your goal:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Groups, Source={StaticResource resultsCollection}}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```